# Primefaces change panel icon

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using  **Primefaces toggleable Panel**

```
 <p:panel id="toggleable" header="Toggleable" toggleable="true" closable="true" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel" style="margin-bottom:20px">
......
</p:panel>
```

Panel expand time has to show icon `ui-icon-minusthick`, and

collapse time to show `ui-icon-plusthick`.

I need to change `ui-icon-plusthick` to  `ui-icon-arrow-4-diag`

How to do this ?, Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your page:

```
.marker .ui-icon-closethick{
    background-position: -16px -80px;
}
```

And this attribute to your panel component:

```
styleClass="marker"
```

Comment: @user5267318, hi, did you try the answer?